# Не получается вытащить элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь со страницы вытащить элемент. Какие то получаются моим способом, а какие то нет. Не пойму почему...
Вот пример:

```
$.get('https://p.ya.ru/saint-petersburg', function(response){

    var qwe = $('body', response).html();
    var qwe2 = $('section.fact', response).html();
    console.log(qwe);
    console.log(qwe2);
});
```

Это почему то не работает..

Но, с этой же страницы получается вытащить div

```
$.get('https://p.ya.ru/saint-petersburg', function(response){

    var qwe = $('div.sparkline', response).html();
    console.log(qwe);
});
```

Comment: А что же в консоли-то?

Comment: В первом случае
   'undefined'
Во втором, содержимое дива

Comment: html код покажите того что выдернуть пытаетесь?

Comment: Да я в принципе ни с какой страницы не могу выдернуть body.

Comment: А вы не думали, что проблема может быть в ограничении на кросдоменные запросы? Если нет, то пора об этом хорошенько задуматься.

Comment: У меня нету этих ограничений. Страница у меня загружается полностью. По вашей логике как тогда у меня второй вариант работает?

Comment: А вы уверены, что он у вас работает? :) Просто JSFiddle с вашим кодом **не** работает по вполне понятным причинам (кроссдоменные запросы)

Comment: Прощу прощения, не та ссылка на JSFiddle. Вот корректная: http://jsfiddle.net/o6dbvmcs/ (все равно не работает)

Comment: Уверен. Я работаю в NW.js, там таких ограничения как кроссдоменные нету!

Comment: AJAX принципиально не может работать между разными доменами - это ограничение безопасности. Именно на эти ограничения вам и намекали. 

Что-бы к удаленному хосту была возможность обращаться по AJAX - там должно быть явно это разрешено:
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` в .htaccess.

Более чем уверен, что администраторы яндекса нормальные параноики и не будут включать эту возможность.

Comment: @maza51 Вы **не управляете** этими ограничениями, они просто есть. (Да-да и в NW.js тоже, потому что он построен на базе Chromium, в котором они есть.) Смиритесь и ищите обходные пути (JSONP, Proxy, ...).